# IE7 floating an image within a li of a scrolllable div

Tags: css

I have a poup that is scrollable, inside of that popup I have some of the li's with borders above and below.  The problem that I am having is that the z-indexed images with the li's in IE7 are not scrolling with copy any ideas?

Anyone?

```
<div class="pop-header-container">   
<ul class="beni-home">
<li class="first"><p>copy</p>
<div class="image-contain">
<img src="IMAGE" class="one-image" />
</div>  
</li>
</ul>
</div>

ul.beni-home {
margin: 0 0 25px;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

ul.beni-home li {
margin: 0;
padding: 25px 0 25px 25px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
background:url("IMAGE") no-repeat 0 30px;
}

ul.beni-home li.first { 
border-top:5px solid #e3e3e3; 
}

/* and the image and container */

.image-contain{position:relative;}

.price-tag
{
float:left;
position:absolute;
left:180px;
top:-50px;
z-index:999999; 
zoom: 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified a DOCTYPE decalaration in your markup? This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
```

Add this to the top of your document.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11851851/419

Comment: Oops, overlooked the flagging aspect of it. Will keep this in mind