# make image element fixed position and doesn't move on scroll

Tags: css

I am trying to make an image stick to left of the page like "Give Feedback" button in:

http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/php/

I have the following HTML code ( i have other codes but just to show an example):

```
<img id="btn" class="btn" src="cl.png" height="161" width="34" alt="clear" />
```

and the following CSS:

```
#btn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 54%;
    z-index: 100001;
    width: 34px;
    height: 168px;
    margin: -45px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

For some reason it's not producing the same effect when I scroll the page. Do I have to use another DIV and wrap the button?

Comment: Could you post a demo, that reproduces your problem, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar, so we can see what's going on?

Comment: What's the result you've got then? And where is #btn in your HTML page? is it directly in the <body> ?

Comment: It works fine for me. It stays fixed on the left side, roughly half-way down. I'm using `Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m`.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention its for IE, i am running version 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you specified a DOCTYPE decalaration in your markup?
This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
```

Add this to the top of your document.

Comment: Always use a DOCTYPE declaration with IE

Comment: Will keep in mind and remember IE is in a world of its own! :) Thanks again

Comment: How on earth is this the answer to the question above?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use position 'sticky'.

You can see the code on the [CodePen Here.](https://codepen.io/haim1993/pen/eLoJwv) or below:

```
.outer { 
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  height: 100px;
  width: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
}

<div class="outer style-one">
  <div class="inner style-two">
    <div class="style-three">
      <a href="#">Feedback</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```